# Syncing the movement of a SKSpriteNode with the rotation of another SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, skaction

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ9r6.png

Above you can see an image of my game. I have enemies spawning and moving down in the y-axis. The player is suppose to shoot down the enemies before they reach the wall. As it is right now, the player is rotating to the location of the touch. What I want is to make the bullets go in the same direction as the rotation. As it is right now, the bullets just go straight ahead. This is the code for the bullets.

```
func spawnBullets(towards point: CGPoint) {
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bullet")
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    bullet.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x + 19, y: 
player.position.y)
    let action = SKAction.move(to: point, duration: 
TimeInterval(1))
    bullet.run(SKAction.repeatForever(action))

    self.addChild(bullet)
}
```

This is the code I have for rotating the player:

```
static let Pi = CGFloat(Double.pi)
static let DegreesToRadians = Pi / 180 

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {
    let curTouch = touches.first!  
    let curPoint = curTouch.location(in: self)

    let deltaX = self.player.position.x - curPoint.x
    let deltaY = self.player.position.y - curPoint.y
    let angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX)

    self.player.zRotation = angle + 90 * GameplayScene.DegreesToRadians

}
```

How can I make so that the direction of the bullets and the players rotation "sync"?

Answer (score 0):

You rotate the player. This is all good. However, if you want to use SKAction, it doesn't take into account the rotation. It just states an absolute position.

What you want is to move the bullets towards the touch location (with a point, not just with an Y):

```
spawnBullet(towards point: CGPoint) {
    // ...
    let action = SKAction.moveTo(location: point, duration: 3.0)
}
```

And you pass the touch position to the function. You will need to get a proper duration for the action, so that the bullet travels at the desired speed.

Comment: I now changed the code and also edited it here. Although I forgot to note that I'm spawning the bullets with a "var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)". But now, with the changes, when I start the game, I get an error instantly saying "GameplayScene spawnBullets]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa4511022f0". Do you know what the problem might be? Also what did you mean with "And you pass the touch position to the function"

Comment: @Flinigan you can get the touch position, right? Now, when the touch occurs, you wanna make this position available to the bullet spawner so that you can direct the bullets towards the good direction.

Comment: As for your error, it occurs because the selector signature does not allow a parameter to be passed to the function.

Comment: Well, I'm very new to the game development, so no :P Unless you mean in the touchesMoved function. I think the easiest way would be if you showed me, since words can make a noobie confused, especially when it comes to game development :D Sorry for retarded comment..

Comment: How you do it will be up to you, but what you basically want is: 1. Touch occurs on the screen, 2. Calculate a point or directional vector 3. Use the variable from #2 to instantiate an SKAction and then bingo. You could also check for at SKPhysicsBody and apply a velocity based on the touch location. Not much more I can do for you, you gotta do your homeworks